# How do i install Aptana 3 on openSUSE Tumbleweed?

Tags: linux, aptana3, opensuse

I am new to openSUSE and having trouble installing Aptana Studio 3 on it.

Any info would be great. I've tried using the instructions from

http://tutorialforlinux.com/2013/02/20/howto-install-gettingstarted-aptana-studio-3-ide-for-html5-css-javascript-php-rubyonrails-linux-debian-wheezy-kde4/

Maybe i don't understand it properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above added linked combined with the following link helped me to resolve this.

link:
https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Installing_Java

Setting Java up prior to the install is essential! :-D